# CSS FlexBox Model: Difference between flex and box-flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using the css flex box model there are many different properties.

**What is the difference between the following properties?**

```
-webkit-flex: 1;
-moz-flex: 1;
-ms-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
```

and

```
-webkit-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
```

**How do I combine the old and the new syntax?**

Comment: not 100% sure, but i think one of them was newer syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`box-flex` is the old flexbox specification: you were allowed to specify one single "flexibility" value instead of the "growing", "shrinking" and "basis" factors values as you can do now

```
      NEW             OLD
flex:1 1 auto; == box-flex:1;
flex:1 0 auto; == no equivalent
```

flex box may look really confusing because there are many specifications involved

functioning is different between each spec, so it's better to define fallbacks in a later moment; especially if you use `-grow` `-shrink` `-basis` and `-wrap` etc, you will need to fallback to a totally different layout

if you are learning, I suggest to use only the new [nearly]standard syntax http://dundalek.com/css3-flexbox-reference/

and in a second time add support for older browser ( not necessarily all )

only MSIE10's and the old `-webkit-` syntaxes (to target old Android phones);
the `-moz-` syntax isn't necessary, IMHO

---

yes, you need the old syntax to support android 2. avoid to use flex-wrap because old browser don't support them (actually even new firefox doesn't support it yet), try to always use flex:1 1 auto; because other values aren't possible with old syntax... space-between and other new flexbox "goodies" don't work in the oldest flexbox spec (but may work in the 2011 spec) so avoid them if possible. basically the safe properties/values are

`flex:` with the value `1 1 auto`

`flex-direction:` (box-orient)

`justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center` (box-pack)

`align-items: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch` (box-align)

Comment: So old Android phones need the old syntax? How do I combine both?

Comment: Is there an overview which notation I have to use specially for webkit for old and new devices?

Comment: Does it matter if I put the old syntax before or after the the new syntax?